# Can't catch exceptions thrown by a template speciailization method

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Let's say I have the following code:

```
//handler.hpp
template<typename T>
class handler
{
private:
    static void process_core(const T& request) { }
public:
    static void process(const T& request)
    {
        try
        {
            process_core(request);
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << "exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

//string_handler.cpp
template<> void handler<std::string>::process_core(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << "string_handler" << std::endl;
    throw std::invalid_argument("bang");
}

//test.cpp
int main()
{
    handler<std::string>::process("123");
}
```

I think the `std::invalid_arguemnt` exception should be caught and handled, but it's not. The program crashes:

```
string_handler
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  bang
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The interesting things are:

1. Changing the method `handler::process_core` to

   ```
   static void process_core(const T& request);  // { } braces are removed
   ```

works. However I can't do this because `process_core` is optional for some types. Q1: why it works after removing braces?

2. Merging the sources into a single file (say `test.cpp`) works. Q2: why?
3. Q3: What's the correct way to implement?

Comment: I thought that bodies for ALL template specializations and implementations of template class member functions MUST be declared outside the class.  You should try declaring the default (empty) body for process_core() outside the class as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should declare your specialization before using it in main, else your program is ill formed. (you have conflicting regular instantiation and specialization one).

- When removing definition with *"1."*, you have no conflict of definition.
- When merging in one file, you declare (and define) the specialization before regular instantiation so it is ok too.
- The way to allow to split in different file is to declare the specialization, so:

  ```
  //handler.hpp

  template<typename T>
  class handler
  {
   // ...
  };

  // Declare specialization
  template<> void handler<std::string>::process_core(const std::string& s);
  ```

Comment: The `T` of `handler` is compiled from generated sources, I don't want to add a lot of header files e.g. XXX_handler.hpp. Any ideas?

Comment: There are 2 typical place to place specialization declaration, Near the method to specialize (as I proposed), near the class for which we do the specialization (So not possible for built-in type, and harder for std/3rd library types).